# Killing a multiprocess pool using a tkinter button

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm building an application that does thousands (possibly millions) of calculations based off of what the user inputs. Because these calculations can take a long time, I want to use Python's multiprocessing module. Here is my dilemma; I want to set up a tkinter window with a cancel button to stop the calculations running throughout the processors I set up using Pool. I tried using threads to allow the popup window to run, but some funny things happen when I run the code.

When I press the 'start' button, the Pool starts going as expected. However, my popup window does not show even though it is on its own thread. Even weirder, when I tell my IDE (PyCharm) to stop the program, the popup window shows and the calculations are still running until I either press the 'exit' button from the popup window, or kill the program altogether.

So my questions are: Why won't my popup window show even though it is on its own thread? Am I utilizing the multiprocessing module correctly? Or is the problem something totally different?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    print(x*x)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1,5))  # simulates long calculations
    # Extra math stuff here...

def processor():
    global calc
    calc = Pool(4)
    calc.map(f, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30])
    print("Done")

def calculation_start():
    p = threading.Thread(target=progress_window)  # Thread to open a new window for the user to cancel a calculation
    p.start()
    processor()  # Calls the function to run the calculations

def progress_window():
    # This is the window that pops up to let a user cancel a calculation.
    popup = tk.Toplevel()
    endButton = ttk.Button(popup, text="End", command=lambda :(calc.terminate()))
    endButton.pack()


master = tk.Tk()

startButton = ttk.Button(master, text="Start", command=calculation_start)
startButton.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

EDIT:
I tried switching the `processor` function to a thread instead of the `progress_window` function.

```
def calculation_start():
    p = threading.Thread(target=processor)  # Thread for the function to run the calculations
    p.start()
    progress_window()  # Open a new window for the user to cancel a calculation
```

My popup window appears and the 'end' button looks like it stops the processor when pressed, but it never continues past that point. It's like it's stuck at `calc.map(f, [1,2,3,...]` in the `processor()` function.

Comment: Try adding an `if __name__ == '__main__':` before the `master = tk.Tk()` and indenting it and the rest of the lines following it.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the suggestion, but it is still encountering the same issue.

Comment: 1. start the process pool once
2. don't use threads in this case
3. to be notified when the pool finishes given tasks, pass a callback that updates your GUI to `pool.apply_async`, `pool.map_async`

Answer (score 0):

From the [`Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) documentation:

> It blocks until the result is ready.

That means that, yes, the work is being done on other threads, but the main thread (the one calling `map`) will not execute anything else until the other threads are complete. You want to use [`map_async`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async) and (for a long-running, interactive process), provide a callback for what to do when the pool is finished (probably hide the pop-up).

If you want your program to simply show the pop-up then exit, you want to use the [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) returned by `map_async`. Set up an idle handler using `after_idle` (See [tkinter universal widget methods](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) and remember you'll need to manually re-add the handler after every call). After each idle call, you could call either `AsyncResult.ready()` or `AsyncResult.get(<timeout>)` to see if the pool has completed. Once it's finished, you're safe to process the results and exit.

Comment: I switched out `map` for `map_async` and it immediately ran the callback and continued running the code after it.  However, it's not waiting for the pool to finish or be terminated to continue though the code (same for the call back. It's called as soon as it starts.). Is it supposed to do that?  Is there a way to make it wait until it's finished or terminated?

Comment: The updated answer handles your run-then-exit scenario.